# Html5 audio player stops playing song in chrome when click other page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html5-audio

i used html5 audio player in my project of asp.net mvc. when i click other page then i have saved that player content in hidden field so it continues with playing songs in firefox but in chrome its pause and stop playing when click another page. is there any way to continues playing song in all browser when click other page.

my code

```
-html
```

```
<audio src="@model.url" preload="none";"></audio>

    <div class="error-message" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="VolumeSliderIcon">
 <div class="divVolumeSlider" id="slider"></div>
  </div>
```

my jquery :

```
 var a = audiojs.createAll({
                    trackEnded: function () {

                    audio.load($('a', next).attr('data-src'));
                      audio.play();     
                    }
                });
```

is there any way or what i have to do in audio.js so my song starts playing in chrome also while click oher pages

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like as given in link bellow
[Don't Stop Audio](http://css-tricks.com/dont-stop-the-audio/)